# Thumb drive doesn't distinguish case in file names on Lubuntu

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, filename, copy, case-insensitive

Using SanDisk ExtremePro 128GB usb3.0 thumb drive to copy files between Lubuntu 13.10 systems, also sometimes from Mac or PCs.  Formatting is standard off-the-shelf, I believe, although I did run a top shareware bitchecker on them before I put them in use.  The SanDisk programs are still there, and I'm not using any of their encryption.

When I copy files from Lubuntu to the thumb drive, although Lubuntu differentiates file-name letter case, and the letter case is retained on the thumb drives, **the thumb drive barfs when two separate files in the same directory have the same name but different case.**  Lubuntu asks "Do you want to skip, overwrite, or rename?".  Not only that, under unusual circumstances--if a default overwrite is in effect-- it will silently RENAME the file to the previous file's case pattern, while overwriting the old file.

Obviously this renders backing up between Lubuntu systems a pain.

I want to be able to use the thumb drive to copy between Lubuntu's without having to worry about case and duplicate file names.  And I want to be able to copy back & forth from a Lubuntu to a Mac or PC too.  The files are large (around a Gig each), so I have to be able to maintain speed.

Is there an easy way to change settings on a SanDisk Extreme Pro so it does this?

Is there a way to format the SanDisk so it can handle both requirements?  What steps would I use to do this on Linux?

Alternatively, is there a way to format the SanDisk so it has two partitions, one that works back & forth for Lubuntu's, and one that can nicely talk with PCs?  What steps?  I'm willing to lose the unique filenames on the partition that can talk with PCs, if I can keep it on the partition used to sneakernet between Lubuntu's.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thumb drive probably has a case insensitive file system. You would need to format it using a case sensitive filesystem do be able to do what you want.

Yes, you can format it to have two partitions, use `gparted` to create a partition table and 2 (or more) partitions on your thumb drive, set the first one as vfat (that´s the one you will be able to use on windows), and the other as ext4 (that´s going to be case-sensitive).

Comment: I believe the ntfs filesystem can optionally be case sensitive/insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Off the shelf format on SanDisk is Fat32 (vfat) which is case insensitive. There are a couple of nice GUIs to repartition your drive, I prefer 'gnome-disks' if available for lubuntu, or gparted as mentioned above.

Comment: gnome-disks formatting results in overly strong protections, won't let you access the disk immediately afterwards & also protection problems in remounting; requires "sudo chown my_user /media/my_user/my_disk_name" for good luck to reset permissions.  Then disk works fine.